# How to model matching of two entities

Tags: entity-framework-core

I've a class called `Access` and a class trying to pick two accesses as a match, like this:

```
public class AccessMatch
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    protected internal int Acces1Id { get; private set; }
    public Access Access1 { get; private set; }
    protected internal int Access2Id { get; private set; }
    public Access Access2 { get; private set; }
}
```

I would like to ensure, that the combination of two accesses can only exist once, and therefore I've created this unique index:

```
builder.HasIndex(x => new { x.Access1Id, x.Access2Id }).IsUnique();
```

But if I already have an row with `Access1Id=10` and `Access2Id=20`, I am still allowed to create a new row with `Access1Id=20` and `Access2Id=10`.

How can I ensure that this is not allowed? Should this be modelled in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

Modify your created unique index and create a unique index on a sorted tuple of `Access1Id` and `Access2Id`. This way, the combination of `Access1Id=20` and `Access2Id=10` will be considered the same as `Access1Id=10` and `Access2Id=20`.

```
builder.HasIndex(x => new Tuple<int, int>(Math.Min(x.Access1Id, x.Access2Id), Math.Max(x.Access1Id, x.Access2Id))).IsUnique();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a custom logic to handle this uniqueness constraint. Create a composite key based on the sorted order of these IDs. Here's how:

```
public class AccessMatch
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Access1Id { get; private set; }
    public Access Access1 { get; private set; }
    public int Access2Id { get; private set; }
    public Access Access2 { get; private set; }

    // Add a computed property for the sorted combination
    public string CombinedIds => $"{Math.Min(Access1Id, Access2Id)}_{Math.Max(Access1Id, Access2Id)}";
}
```

And in your database configuration:

```
builder.HasIndex(x => x.CombinedIds).IsUnique();
```

This update brings a `CombinedIds` property that represents a unique combination of `Access1Id` and `Access2Id` regardless of their order. It concatenates the IDs in sorted order separated by an underscore.

Comment: Thanks for this approach, but should `CombinedIds` be a property with both a setter and getter? I get an "no backing field could be found" error with this approach.